# Weird session scope reverse is possible in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I insert data from a #temp table
into a permanent table which is passed as varchar variable?

I am asking the opposite transfer of:

```
Declare @anytable varchar(99)='perma'
--insertexec
Insert into #temptablecreatedalready
Exec('select * from '+ @anytable)
```

Comment: Just use dynamic SQL and build the appropriate insert statement.

Comment: There is a problem with the scope within and outside of dynamic SQL for temporaries

Comment: Temp tables still exist inside dynamic SQL.

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: Your point was correct. Just that i wanted this to be available and answered on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the select alone in the query string, try the whole insert.

```
Declare @anytable = 'perma'
EXEC(
'Insert into ' + @anytable + '
select * from #temptablecreatedalready')
```

Make sure that the `#temptablecreatedalready` table is created in the current session before the query string is executed.

Comment: My friend, my question is about inserting into permanent table

Comment: Then just change that Temp to a permanent table by inverting the table names in the query string

Comment: The circle is complete. Even here